# Different entity framework versions in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a .NET project that uses entity framework 4 for its database model. However, it has a very clumsy data layer build on top and we decided to stop using it. We recently upgraded the project to .NET 4 and me and my colleagues were thinking whether to start using EF 6 (which from what I read is supported in .NET 4).

So my question is: is it possible to create a new db model with EF 6, without having to remove the old one? Or will the EF upgrade interfere with the already existing model? Some of the guys working on this project area really used to the old data-layer and we certainly do not want to force them to move to a new one.

Comment: You can have separate contexts, if that's what you mean, but not different versions of the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally possible. Normally it is not supported, BUT...

...with EF 6 Microsoft made updated independent of the .NET framework. For that they had to move it out of the .NET framework libraries. Which means that they.... had to change namespaces.

So, EF 6 uses separate dll's AND sepate namespaces from V4, which means they SHOULD nicely coexist. No guarantees, but at least this makes it possible to make a try - it is an edge case and I think most people will just go all in on a new version.

If you read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6

you can see that the namespaces have changed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, in the link that you provided there is this: "Installing the EF6 NuGet package should automatically remove any references to System.Data.Entity from your project for you.". Which means that I will have to do a lot of manual work if I want to preserve both models. The project is really large and complex, so I will have to think if it is worth the effort.

Comment: Noone says you will not have a lot of manual work. I personally think it is not worth it, but that evaluation is not something I Can do - and was not part of your question.